# How is Spark using 15 cores when I only have 4 on a m4.xlarge EMR instance?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, emr, amazon-emr

I have looked at the answer to

[Why is Spark detecting 8 cores, when I only have 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37632396/why-is-spark-detecting-8-cores-when-i-only-have-4)

And it doesn't seem to explain the following scenario: I am setting the `spark.executor.cores` at 5. I have `spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled` set to true. According to the Spark History Server, my 10 node cluster is running 30 executors, indicating that spark is using 3 executors per node. This seems to suggest that 15 cores are available (3 executors x 5 cores) per node. The specs for an m4.xlarge instance are 4 vCPUs with 16 GB of memory. Where are these extra cores coming from?

Note: I am setting `spark.executor.memory` at `3g` and `yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb` at 12200.

Comment: You have 2, not 4... https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/virtualcores/

Comment: @cricket_007 I believe that is innaccurate: https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/. Also the lscpu command shows 4 CPUs.

Comment: Cores are not the same as vCPU, the latter being **virtual**, whereas cores are a physical limitation of the server, from which EMR scales up and down, so there's no ideal way to know what the actual server resources are acquired